# How to use functions within a PHP without soft coding it inside the actual HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html

For example, in an HTML for registration once submitted executes the PHP file and whatever functions it has inside. I am trying to have the HTML registration form continue to another HTML registration form while performing the needed PHP code at the same time.

> Registration.html > (Process PHP) > homePage.html ("Thank you for
>   registering!")

The way I learned to do it was through

> registration.html > (process PHP) > homepage.PHP

If you are wondering why, it is because I can't display any of the HTML contents if the format is in PHP.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Do you need http://php.net/require ?

Comment: If this is the issue " I can't display any of the HTML contents if the format is in PHP.", then the answer is yes you can do it with echo ... <?php echo '<p>my page</p>'; ?> Here is a sample with 2 pages: http://wistudat.be/try/go1.php

Comment: Fix your php html rendering issue

Answer (score 1):

You can send the form data to the php page, which will process it, then once the data is processed you can redirect to another html file using

```
header("Location:homePage.html");
```

Comment: Form data is sent, when you are heading to a different URL oo?

Comment: I think its way better to use forms, which redirect you to a different script/src/URL.

Comment: @Xatenev Yes, but only if you set the HTTP status to `308` instead of the default redirect ^_^

Comment: Could you please do a sample on that? I'd very much like to see one!